# Unity 3D Error Saying: an error occurred while resolving packages: one or more packages could not be added to the local file system unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a project on version 2021.3.8f1 and in any project an error occurs:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEEOa.png)

how can i solve it? I already tried everything: delete manifest.json, delete package.lock.json, reset all packages, update all packages to latest version in package manager and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to delete the Library folder and have Unity rebuild the structure of you project the next time you open it up.
Delete the Library folder.

Comment: Still Nothing. But, If I run the project for the second time, the new error appears: https://imgur.com/a/LJZCVke
I didn't change the version.